# APPCRASH StackOverflowException clr.dll c00000fd

Tags: c#, .net, stack-overflow

I am running a .Net console application that executes 24 hrs a day. It has a bug that occurs about once every 6 days.

I would like your assistance to fix this bug. First I will provide some background, and then I will provide the exception messaging.

Unfortunately I do not have steps to reproduce. You will see why as you read on.

First some background:

I have robust exception handling in my code (or so I thought). For example I have a try...catch block in my Main() method that captures any unhandled exceptions and if they are FATAL it restarts the underlying task. It works great for any exceptions generated from my own code.

I cannot explain why the below exception isn't handled in my code. My best guess is that clr.dll exceptions do not get caught within the managed stack. And if that is the case, I do not know how to generate a stack trace. I don't even know where to begin to fix this.

The process I am running is using the following versions and modules:

- C# .Net Framework 4.6.1
- Console App project type
- System.Net.WebClient
- log4net
- Windows 7 64-bit

At the time of the crash I checked RAM and HDD: both have plenty of free space.

About the code I'm executing. The process is a continous loop that downloads data from a website and saves it to a text file. If there is an error, it is logged using log4net.

The basic loop is this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    return new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
                }
                catch 
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500); // slow it down.
                }
            }
```

The following is the only message that displays in my console window when the exception occurs: (no stack trace displayed)

```
Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException
```

My console application completely freezes up and a dialog window pops up with the following information (closing this dialog also terminates my application)

```
 Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: foo.goo.BatchExecutor.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    5a50f3eb
  Fault Module Name:    clr.dll
  Fault Module Version: 4.7.2117.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   59cf5105
  Exception Code:   c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 0002429f
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 28e8
  Additional Information 2: 28e8aacd8abfe32876bc8363e8e5c526
  Additional Information 3: 6916
  Additional Information 4: 6916665ca52ff482d854f190abcf46b2
```

The only other place I could find information about the crash is in the Windows Event Log:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          1/23/2018 5:51:46 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      FOOGOO
Description:
Faulting application name: foo.goo.BatchExecutor.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5a50f3eb
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.7.2117.0, time stamp: 0x59cf5105
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0002429f
Faulting process id: 0x1e00
Faulting application start time: 0x01d39169354e41a7
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\SHARED\foo.goo.BatchExecutor\foo.goo.BatchExecutor.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 21b9b2a4-00a9-11e8-9f6c-94c69110a719
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-01-24T01:51:46.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1852</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>FOOGOO</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>foo.goo.BatchExecutor.exe</Data>
    <Data>1.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>5a50f3eb</Data>
    <Data>clr.dll</Data>
    <Data>4.7.2117.0</Data>
    <Data>59cf5105</Data>
    <Data>c00000fd</Data>
    <Data>0002429f</Data>
    <Data>1e00</Data>
    <Data>01d39169354e41a7</Data>
    <Data>C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\SHARED\foo.goo.BatchExecutor\foo.goo.BatchExecutor.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll</Data>
    <Data>21b9b2a4-00a9-11e8-9f6c-94c69110a719</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

*****UPDATE WITH SOLUTION WORKAROUND *****

I have given up trying to handle this exception within .Net. I found an effective workaround. This workaround applies to Windows, specifically any version with an Event Viewer.

Workaround Instructions.

1) Open control panel->Admin Tools->Event Viewer->Windows Logs->Applications.

2) Select the offending event. In my case, it is state ERROR, and matches the example that you see above.

3) On the right hand side click "Attach Task to This Event".

4) Complete the wizard. In my case, I restart my application.

5) Save the task.

6) Now switch over to Task Scheduler and find the task. Click Properties. Click through the tabs and configure the Task as you see fit.

Comment: I had the same exact problem where my console app is closed without any reason at all , no exceptions is caught and no job is terminated . i just switched to use WindowsForm and the application is never closed even when the job which can take up to (5-6 days) is terminated

Comment: Yes StackOverflow will kill process and you get that error... but no, this question in current state is not answerable and hence off-topic on SO. (Code in the post very unlikely to be related at all)

Comment: You said you "restart" your app... can you post that code? I suspect it's might be the culprit, maybe you don't really "restart" it but just start another one without cleaning up the old one properly...

Comment: Check for any place in your code where you might do recursion; we had a bug that triggered this years ago because in some error cases we got ourselves into a recursive loop.

Comment: Also agree that this is a recursion issue.  Your "basic loop" is incomplete, as this would only run 5 times. Can you post the full code for your loop so we can see how you're calling it?

Comment: If it is recursion shouldn't I be seeing an exception that I can manage? I can easily write some code that does recursion that builds an object graph that exceeds RAM. But then if I do that, I get a managed exception. If this issue is caused by recursion, etc. why is it not appearing as a managed exception?

Comment: might be related, might be not but this is not how you should be using a WebClient. [You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilising your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) - have a one static instance and work on that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*****UPDATE WITH SOLUTION WORKAROUND *****

I have given up trying to handle this exception within .Net. I found an effective workaround. This workaround applies to Windows, specifically any version with an Event Viewer.

Workaround Instructions.

1) Open control panel->Admin Tools->Event Viewer->Windows Logs->Applications.

2) Select the offending event. In my case, it is state ERROR, and matches the example that you see above.

3) On the right hand side click "Attach Task to This Event".

4) Complete the wizard. In my case, I restart my application.

5) Save the task.

6) Now switch over to Task Scheduler and find the task. Click Properties. Click through the tabs and configure the Task as you see fit.

Answer (score 3):

I suggests to use [ProcDump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump), it can be configured to generate a crash dump when the StackOverflowException occurs.

```
procdump -accepteula -e 1 -f C00000FD.STACK_OVERFLOW -g -ma <PID> <OUTPUT PATH>
```

Then analyze the dump file using one of this tools
[Visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-dump-files?view=vs-2019), [windbg](http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/debug-stack-overflow-exception/), [debugdiag](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924), [clrmd](https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd/).

Answer (score 1):

To help collect a stack trace, PHPTower, you can do what I did and subscribe to the [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception) event of your program at the beginning of your `Main()` function

The signature of the event handler looks like the following, allowing you to get the exception, and output a stack trace with the [`Exception.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.tostring) method.

```
    private static void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        File.AppendAllLines(FileName, e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
    }
```

Happy hunting!
-cadatoiva

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying DebugDiag (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) to capture the crash and analyse the resulting process dump. Make sure you include pdbs alongside your exe, to make diagnosis easier: in the Project properties, Build tab: set the Configuration to the configuration that you use to build the exe. In the Output section, Advanced button, set the Debugging information to Pdb (or Full).